How to resolve compatibility issues caused by fixed gaps to make the layout adaptable to different devices
Here is my code, it works great in my computer. However, "gap: 50px", this fixed gap makes it lose compatibility.On other computers, the content might overflow the container.
<style scoped lang="scss">
    .course-home-layout {
        display: flex;
        align-items: flex-start;
        justify-content: space-between;
        gap: 50px;
        background-color: var(--background-color);
        width: 80%;
        margin: 20px auto;
        border-radius: 8px;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 3px var(--border-color);
    }
    .content-container {
        margin-left: 20px;
        width: 70%;
    }
    .aside-container {
        width: 30%;
    }
</style>


Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

To make your layout more adaptable and resolve the issues caused by fixed gap: 50px, you can use relative units (like rem, %, vw, etc.) and make adjustments based on the viewport size.
Instead of using a fixed 50px gap, consider using relative units or media queries to adjust the gap based on the screen size. For example, using rem or percentages for the gap will scale better across different devices.
